# Python Pandas: How to replace values more efficiently in terms of memory?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some large data frames that I need to replace its values. This operation, however, is killing me and is causing my machine to run out of memory:

```
# replace nan with missing string
df[col].replace(np.nan, '<missing>', inplace=True)
## Unable to allocate 2.11 GiB for an array with shape (45, 6286166) and data type object
```

Is there another way to go about replacing values that does not involve such a high cost?

Comment: iterate through and reassign with `at` or `iat`.  Provide an example and I'll show you what I mean.  Click and read this -> [mcve]

Comment: what about `fillna()`? `df[col].fillna('<missing>')`

Comment: Ah, I did not think about `fillna()` but will try it!

Comment: use a re.sub and iterrate your dataframe using iterrows().  update using loc or iloc.   you will never run out of memory.